# connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work

Tags: c++, qt

I've made separate functions for open and close connection.But it wont let me to add new record on new form.
this is login header file.

```
public:
QSqlDatabase mydb;
void connClose()
{

    //QString connection;
    //connection = mydb.connectionName();
    mydb.close();
    //mydb.removeDatabase(connection);
    mydb.removeDatabase(mydb.connectionName());
}
bool connOpen()
{
    mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mydb.setDatabaseName("./Poem.db");
    if(mydb.open())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(!mydb.open())
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

this is the other form add button :

```
QString Title,Group,Poem;

Title = ui->lineEdit->text();
Group = ui->label_2->text();
Poem = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();



MainWindow mainwindow;
mainwindow.connOpen();



 QSqlQuery * qry1 = new QSqlQuery(mainwindow.mydb);

 qry1->prepare("insert into Poems(Title,Poem,Group) values ('"+Title+"','"+Poem+"','"+Group+"')");

 if(qry1->exec())
 {
     QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("درج شعر جدید"),tr("شعر اضافه شد"));
     mainwindow.connClose();
 }
```

I get this errors :

duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.

Answer (score 3):

You are committing *exactly* what [Qt QSqlDatabase Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase) warns about:

> Warning: There should be no open queries on the database connection
>   when this function is called

...

> // WRONG

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("sales");
QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("sales"); // will output a warning
```

> // "db" is now a dangling invalid database connection, // "query"
>   contains an invalid result set

**and the correct is**:

```
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("sales");
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
}
```

> // Both "db" and "query" are destroyed because they are out of scope

```
  QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("sales"); // correct
```

---

So in your case you execute query `qry1` and remove the database within same scope (i.e before `qry1` goes out of scope), you should modify your code to make sure `qry1` is executed and gets destroyed / goes out of scope / before deleting the database. Try this:

```
{
 QSqlQuery * qry1 = new QSqlQuery(mainwindow.mydb);
 qry1->prepare("insert into Poems(Title,Poem,Group) values ('"+Title+"','"+Poem+"','"+Group+"')");
 if(qry1->exec())
 {
     QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("درج شعر جدید"),tr("شعر اضافه شد"));
 }
}
     mainwindow.connClose();
```

Comment: I've done what you suggested me. But it doesn't work. When i click button on login windows to add record in another form the error pops up.

Comment: Here is the code in login windows when i push add button :void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    connClose();
    FrmNew frmnew;
    frmnew.setModal(true);
    frmnew.exec();
}

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri, its difficult to follow like this, put your real code in the question , you are still doing same problem

Comment: I still have problem with opening and closing database.