# SQLite C++ Qt update query execute but not write to database file

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

When I push the button everything seems ok and the `messagebox` show me that the query has executed successfully. But in the database, nothing has changed.
I got still problems with opening and closing database.

[connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524866/connection-qt-sql-default-connection-is-still-in-use-all-queries-will-cease-t)

---

**I get two errors:**

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
```

but in the same way with these errors, I can insert into my database

---

**here is the code:**

```
#include "frmupdate.h"
#include "ui_frmupdate.h"
#include <mainwindow.h>
#include <qsqlquery.h>
#include <qmessagebox.h>

frmUpdate::frmUpdate(QString &cell1, QString &cell2, QString  &cell3, int &index, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->lineEdit->setText(cell1);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(cell3);
    ui->textEdit->setText(cell2);

    QString st;
    st.setNum(index);
    ui->label_3->setText(st);
    ind = index;
}

frmUpdate::~frmUpdate()
{
    delete ui;
}

void frmUpdate::on_btnUpdate_clicked()
{
    QString Title, Group, Poem;

    Title = ui->lineEdit->text();
    Group = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    Poem = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

    MainWindow mainwindow;
    //mainwindow.connOpen();

    QSqlQuery * qry1 = new QSqlQuery(mainwindow.mydb);

    qry1->prepare("update Poems set Title='"+Title+"',Poem='"+Poem+"',Grp='"+Group+"' where ID='"+ind+"' ");


    if(qry1->exec())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("ویرایش شعر "),tr("شعر ویرایش شد"));
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("ویرایش شعر"),"error");
    }

}

void frmUpdate::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Recommendation: SO is a site where the language used is English and if you have a code that everything is in English, it is difficult to understand what is the purpose of your project for someone who does not know anything about your language like me.

Comment: I can speak your language. If it's necessary i could make a repo in github with english or spanish version of project. The project almost is done only i got this problem with updating records.

Comment: Your code has serious memory errors, you are creating dynamic memory unnecessarily, remember that C++ gives you freedom of access to memory, and you are responsible for its use. For another in English is enough.

Comment: On the other hand your program is susceptible to SQL injection, I would not say that only that is missing

Comment: I really appreciate it if give me a hand with making it better. I just invite you to my project in github.

Comment: Translated into English and I can help you

Comment: I just translate it to english https://github.com/sudebiar/Poem_English